# Как правильно реализовать конструктор с параметром в производном классе?

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        int ab, ac;
        A(int a, int b){
            ab=a;
            ac=b;
            cout<<ab<<"\n"<<ac<<endl;
        };
};
class B:public A{
};
int main() {
    A a(12,12);
    return 0;
}
```

Объявляю класс "A", класс "B", который производный от "A". В конструкторе с параметрами класса "B" хочу сделать использование конструктора с параметрами базового класса. Не понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор дочернего класса (`A`) вызывается в разделе инициализации.

Типа,

```
class B:public A
{
    int cc;
public:
    B(int a, int b, int c):A(a,b) { cc = c; }   
};
```

И вообще, ст*о*ит почитать о разделе инициализации, потому что лучше писать

```
A(int a, int b):ab(a),ac(b)
{
        cout<<ab<<"\n"<<ac<<endl;
};
```

ну, и, соответственно,

```
B(int a, int b, int c):A(a,b),cc(c){}
```

потому что так выполняется именно *инициализация*, а не *присваивание*, а это могут быть в некоторых ситуациях принципиально разные вещи...